# What is the status of configurable absolute reference paths in typescript

Tags: typescript

Having to use relative paths in references like this seems very fragile

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/react/react.d.ts" />
```

Is there a way to pass the compiler a global path to look for type definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin Vseticka notes, it’s not possible to give the compiler an include-path, but it is not necessary to put references to declaration files inside of reference comments. In fact, I consider it an anti-pattern to do so, because these imported declarations apply globally, which means you can easily end up in situations where you remove a source file that has your only reference comment in it and then other files that relied indirectly on those imports break.

Instead, you can pass the declaration files to the compiler the same as the rest of your code (i.e. either on the command line or through tsconfig.json), and they will be processed the same as the rest of your code. So if you run tsc, you can just write `tsc my.ts typings/react/react.d.ts`, or if you use tsconfig.json instead, just add it to the `files` array.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be implemented according to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/293#issuecomment-96853514:

> We consider this thing to be outside the scope of tsc, which we
>   generally think of a compiler that does what it needs to and nothing
>   extra. External build systems that understand TypeScript can provide
>   this functionality themselves and provide better flexibility and
>   configurability.